# Is it possible to create a video chat site without JavaScript?

Tags: php, python, html5-video, html5-audio, tor

I want to create a video chat site for hidden services. But in order to preserve anonymity, it has to be JavaScript-free and plugin-free. Only languages I can think of are Python and PHP, and I want to implement that in HTML5 video.

Comment: I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question). Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

You can do video chat using webrtc and html5 video without javascript.

Comment: Can you send a link? The one I found is dependent on JS. I viewed the page source by right-clicking.